# How can I Show Previous Page Item in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, androiddesignsupport

I am having a viewPager with three images in each page. But the problem is that the number of images in each page are not fixed , means if number of images in last page is less than three then one image from previous page is to be shown there. Please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: can you share your code I mean what you have tried ?

Comment: How are you picking these images? Do you use any order for those images? If not than maybe try to somehow save references to the three images from secon page.